# Calling Rmakdown document in a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a `test.Rmd` file that has the following YAML content plus some other code chunks and statements:

```
---
title: "Rmarkdown test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
params:
     product: "abc"
     type: "xyz"
---
```

I would like to call this from a Shiny application and embed the result of rendering this test.Rmd file in the shiny output

How do I call this from server.R ? I tried `output$text<-render::rmarkdown('test.Rmd)`, with error `Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$defineOutput(name, value, label) :
  Unexpected character output for text` But I see that it generated the `test.html` file in the same location where ui.R and server.R are present.

The ui.R entry I tested is `htmlOutput("text")` with same error as above.

What is the correct way of calling the .Rmd file and generate the output in the shiny output window and also while calling .Rmd how to over-write the parameters? Any help?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this problem, because I have the same problem. I need the code to be included in server.R and ui.R

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

First: Render your rmarkdown using:

```
rmarkdown::render()
```

Second: Call the generated html file using:

```
includeScript()
```

**Solution 2:**

```
HTML(markdownToHTML(text = "_Hello_, \*\*World\*\*!"))
```

**Solution 3:**

Here is another way which I separated Sever and ui and added a couple of fancy modifications:

**Sever:**

```
// generate your report using test.Rmd
generateReport <- function() {
  out.markdown <- ''
  withProgress(message = 'Generating Report',
               value = 0, {
                 out.markdown <- rmarkdown::render(
                   input = "test.Rmd",
                   output_format = "html_document")

                 setProgress(1)
               })

  read_file(out.markdown)
}

// load generateReport function and
// renderText helps function be called whenever it is needed
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$report <- renderText({ HTML(generateReport()) })


// Your rest of code

}
```

**ui.R**

```
// load report in ui
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MY Summary"),

  sidebarLayout(
     mainPanel(htmlOutput("report"))
  )
))
```

Comment: Could you please give us an example code that we should include in shiny app. For example, I have test.Rmd which should be call. Now what code should I include in serverR and ui.R? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did two steps: 1) Render the Rmd to an HTML file called `background.HTML` that I stored to the directory containing the Shiny `app.R`, and 2) includeHTML to load rendered HTML into the `tabPanel`. Here is Part 1:

```
---
title: "Background Info"
date: "November 24, 2019"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: cerulean
    toc: no
---
<style>
.main-container {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

Then here I put my text that I wanted in the `tabPanel` of the Shiny app
```

Here is part 2 that I put in the UI section of my Shiny app:

```
mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Descriptive Stats", div(tableOutput("descstatstable"), style = "font-size:90%")), 
        tabPanel("Background Info", includeHTML("background.html"))
    )
)
```